# How to spread string across multiple lines

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a script `script.py` accepting some command line arguments, and a bash script `main.sh` that calls it with multiple combinations as defined below. Now contrary to my example below the variables `MYARGS` and`MOREARGS` contain a larger number of arguments (10-20 or so). For this reason I thought it would be more readable to split these strings up into multiple lines, with one argument/value pair per line. Is there a way to use multiline strings or are there any ways we can break it up?

```bash
MYARGS="--a=\"asdf\" --b=2.61828" # <- break this into two or more lines?
MOREARGS="--c 31415"
python script.py $MYARGS
python script.py $MYARGS $MOREARGS
```

where `script.py` is

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--a')
parser.add_argument('--b')
parser.add_argument('--c')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Comment: Just end each line with space + backslash and continue on next line. Or use a bash array: `MYARGS=("--a=\"asdf\""); MYARGS+=("--b=2.61828")...` with one item per line, and then: `python script.py "${MYARGS[@]}"`.

Comment: Note that you almost certainly want `MYARGS="-a=asdf"` instead of `MYARGS="-a=\"asdf\""`.  The program accepting the arguments (probably) does not expect to see the double quotes, but the shell is not going to remove them when it parses the string `python script.py $MYARGS $MOREARGS`

Comment: While you can escape a line end using a backslash, I recommend against putting more than one argument into a single variable: It works in your concrete example, but it will bite you sooner or later. Instead, use an array to store the arguments, as RenaudPacalet suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quoted string can span multiple lines. This script:

```
MYARGS="-a=asdf
-b=2.1828
-c=foo
"

echo $MYARGS
```

Produces as output:

```
-a=asdf -b=2.1828 -c=foo
```

This works fine, but it ends up getting tricky when you have arguments that contain whitespace. In that case, it generally makes more sense to use [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html), assuming that you're working with Bash (or another modern shell):

```
MYARGS=(
    -a="this has whitespace"
    -b=2.1828  # I can even include inline comments!
    -c=foo
)
MOREARGS="--c 31415"

python script.py "${MYARGS[@]}"
python script.py "${MYARGS[@]}" $MOREARGS
```

In the above, `MYARGS` is an array, but `MOREARGS` is a simple scalar variable.